# max number of elements for a jdbc connection's `createArrayOf`

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I want to do something like:

```java
Integer[] largeIntArray = new Integer[]{ 1, 2, 3 }; // possibly 50k elements
List<Integer> result = jdbc.query(conn -> {
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT number FROM something WHERE id = ANY(?)");
    ps.setArray(1, conn.createArrayOf("INTEGER", largeIntArray));
    return ps;
}, (rs, rowNum) -> rs.getInt(1));
```

Using `org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection#createArrayOf`.

The `result` is not a problem, I can use a cursor.

How many elements can `largeIntArray` contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection#createArrayOf` return an implementation of Array.

The theoretical limit for an Array implementation capacity is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `2^31 - 1`, or `2,147,483,647`.

**Digression:**

I've read that an Integer object should be around `16 bytes`.

This `max limit` * `16` get you around 34GB so with a classical General public server config (generally 32GB) you will probably run into an out of memory error before attaining the max limit.

Note that it would be impossible on a 32-bit os, those ones going up to 4GB memory.